# Unable to set state in React after receiving API call response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So, I'm building a multi-page wizard component in react.
I'm using functional components.
Parent component holds the state.
Each "Step" (Step1, Step2, etc.) page is called by switch statement in the Parent component.

My problem is that in my Step2 page, I pass in an "array" of items and receive an "array" response from an API call but it fails to set the state with that response as I intended.

Here's the Parent component's state:

```
  const [colorLinks, setColorLinks] = useState({
      red: [],
      blue: [],
      green: [],
      cyan: [],
      black: [],
      white: [],
      purple: [],
      gold: [],
      lightgreen: [],
      magenta: [],
      orange: [],
      gray: [],
      sepia: [],
      copper: [],
      pink: [],
      brown: [],
      beige: [],
  })
```

Here's the code written in the Parent component to make the requests asynchronously and these are passed as props to Step2:

```
const functionWithPromise = item => { //a function that returns a promise
  return Promise.resolve('ok')
}

const anAsyncFunction = async (item, setColorLinks) => {
        let post = {
          "request": {
            "url": "http://colorendpoints.com/",
            "color": item
          }
        }
        let endpointurl = `http://localhost:8021/&url=http://colorendpoints.com/`;
        let result;
    
        try {
          result = await fetch(endpointurl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(post),
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
          })
          console.log('Successfully completed post request!')
          result = await result.json()
          result = result.items[0] // because it arrives as an array with items I need in 0th position
          setColorLinks({
                  red: result.red,
                  blue: result.blue,
                  green: result.green,
                  cyan: result.cyan,
                  black: result.black,
                  white: result.white,
                  purple: result.purple,
                  gold: result.gold,
                  lightgreen: result.lightgreen,
                  magenta: result.magenta,
                  orange: result.orange,
                  gray: result.gray,
                  sepia: result.sepia,
                  copper: result.copper,
                  pink: result.pink,
                  brown: result.brown,
                  beige: result.beige,
          })
          return functionWithPromise(result)
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Got an error...e')
          console.log()
          return functionWithPromise(e)    
        }
}

const getData = async () => {
  return Promise.all(list.map(item => anAsyncFunction(item)))
}
```

Still in the Parent component, I then pass the above (`getData`, `colorLinks`, and `setColorLinks`) into Step2 like so:

```
<Step2 
    getData={getData}
    colorLinks={colorLinks}
    setColorLinks={setColorLinks}
/>
```

My list: `['color1', 'color2', 'color1', ...]`

Despite doing the above, I cannot get `colorLinks` to update with the incoming response.
I can clearly see the successful responses in the console but `setColorLinks` is **completely ignored**.
I definitely get the resulting array from calling `getData` but even with a for loop it considers the result undefined.
How can I solve this and update the state with the results of the API call?
Why won't `setColorLinks` update the state within my async map functions?

Comment: Does your code `catch`? If so, what is `e`?

Comment: It's called within `getData` like so: `const getData = async () => {
  return Promise.all(list.map(item => anAsyncFunction(item)))
}`

Comment: @JakeWorth Yes, it catches, the `e` means `error`

Comment: What is the error? Try `console.log(e)` inside of your `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from this function

```
const getData = async () => {
  return Promise.all(list.map(item => anAsyncFunction(item)))
}
```

You are using setColorLink in a map, meaning you are calling setColorLink many times. However, setState is an async request - You end up overwriting each state with a new setState.

I'm not sure what is `list`, and what this `.map` is for. If you need to loop through an array of items and fetch them. You should do something like this.

```
const getData = async () => {
  const result = await Promise.all(list.map(item => anAsyncFunction(item)))
  setColorLink(result) //<- set state here, not inside Promise.all
}
```

Your list is an array of colours, but colorLink is only an object of colours. Is colorLink meant to be an array of object of colours?

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was exactly the problem.